# Codeigniter MySQL now() time

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, timezone, timestamp

I use codeigniter and I have my site on a British server (I'm from Denmark) and I use timestamp and on my MySQL server, but when I echo it out from the database it is 7 hours ahead.

Do you know what I can do? Do I need to make a function or something? I don't want to type a lot of stuff in all my queries.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: you could try modifying `date_default_timezone_set(Asia/Krasnoyarsk);` (+7 hours I believe) in your php.ini - it won't effect MySQL at least, but it may help with any of CI's date helpers etc. [more @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding 7 hours to your timestamp ALWAYS? If it always has +7 hours, it could be an answer:

```
$mydate = date("Y-m-d g:i a");
$timestamp = strtotime($mydate);

$SERVER_HOURS = 7;
$server_timestamp = $timestamp+60*60*$SERVER_HOURS;
```

Comment: This answer will be flawed out if you have daylight savings..!!  Perhaps setting a Time Zone will be far better than hard-coding the values.